# How do you modify an array of char after it's been declared in a class?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a header file that declares a class, and a member variable of type pointer to char,

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();

    char *myString;
};
```

and a .cpp file that defines the class and its constructer, and defines the member variable within the constructer.

```
#include "header.h"

MyClass::MyClass() {
    myString = "Hello";
}

int main() {
    MyClass myClass;
    printf(myClass.myString);
    return 0;
}
```

myString = "Hello" doesn't work, it gives the error 'argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"'. How do I modify the array after it's been declared?

Comment: `myString = "Hello";` shouldn't work. `"Hello"` is a `const char*` and `myString` is a `char*`. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/EDdFQo

Comment: A pointer to characters isn't a string. It's just a pointer to a single character.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry, I should have said in the question that I got that error. Is there a way to modify the array?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I thought an array was just a pointer to the first item? I get the same error if I declare the variable as char myString[];.

Comment: @TurtleMenistan An array is *not* just a pointer. But, please use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `"Hello"` can't be changed, so no. You'll have to allocate memory `myString = new char[<size>];` and then `delete[] myString;` afterwards. Better: Use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *insist* on using old, 'C-style' character strings, then you should declare your `myString` array **as an actual array** rather than a pointer to unallocated memory:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    char myString[MAXLENGTH]; // Where MAXLENGTH is what you decide is the max size
};
```

And then, in your constructor, use the `strcpy` function to initialize the array:

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass() {
    strcpy(myString, "Hello");
}
```

An alternative, in order to keep the `char *myString` version, would be to explicitly allocate the memory in the constructor (not forgetting to `delete[]` the array in the destructor):

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    char *myString;
};

//...

MyClass::MyClass() {
    myString = new char[MAXLENGTH];
    strcpy(myString, "Hello");
}
MyClass::~MyClass() {
    delete[] myString;
}
```

But, as you're using `C++`, you'd be *far* better off using `std::string` and the many operations that standard class provides.

Comment: OP, if you go for the manual `new`/`delete`, don't forget about the [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 2):

String literal `"Hello"` is of type `const char[6]` or `const char*` if you will, whereas your `myString` variable is of type `char*`. Up to C++03 this implicit conversion was tolerated and you could have:

```
char* mystring = "Hello";
```

Starting with C++11, that is no longer the case. You will need the appropriate `const char*` type instead:

```
char const* mystring = "Hello";
```

That being said, in C++ you should use the [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) type instead:

```
std::string mystring = "Hello";
```

Comment: "String literal "Hello" is of type const char[]" - Actually, it is of type `const char [6]`.